# Database will read but will not write

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a problem where I am unable to make a booking to a Sql server .mdf database, but I am able to read to it.

No error messages occur and I have tried everything I can think of. Any help will be highly appreciated and thanks in advance!
Here is the code used for the insert into command:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim SQLCode As New SQLCode
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim lrd As SqlDataReader
    Dim inscmd As New SqlCommand

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffInitials", lblStaffInitials.Text.Trim())
    lblStaffInitials.Text = lblStaffInitials.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Week", lblWeek.Text.Trim)
    lblWeek.Text = lblWeek.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", (lblPeriod.Text.Trim))
    lblPeriod.Text = lblPeriod.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", lblDay.Text.Trim)
    lblDay.Text = lblDay.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", lblSubject.Text.Trim)
    lblSubject.Text = lblSubject.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearGroup", lblYear.Text.Trim)
    lblYear.Text = lblYear.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberOfPupils", (lblNoOfPupils.Text.Trim))
    lblNoOfPupils.Text = lblNoOfPupils.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ControlledAssesment", lblControlledAssesment.Text.Trim)
    lblControlledAssesment.Text = lblControlledAssesment.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Room", lblRoom.Text.Trim)
    lblRoom.Text = lblRoom.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Session", txtSession.Text.Trim)
    txtSession.Text = txtSession.Text

con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RoomBookingSystem.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
    Try
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString)
            con.Open()
            inscmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Booking (Week, Day, Period, Subject, YearGroup, StaffInitials,NumberOfPupils,Session,Room,ControlledAssesment) VALUES (@Week,@Day,@Period,@Subject,@YearGroup,@StaffInitials, @NumberOfPupils,@Session,@Room,@ControlledAssesment)"
            inscmd.Connection = con
            inscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            inscmd.Parameters.Clear()
        End Using

    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
    MsgBox("Your Booking Has Been Made Successfully")
    Clicky = False
    MainViewForm.btnBackToBooking.Visible = False
    FormView.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to overwrite your mdf-file on each build?

Comment: you have `Finally` without a Try, how does that work? just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the problem lies within the databases location.

When the program is debugged a **copy of your database** is placed within the bin/debug folder, if you look in here you will see the copy and your code will right to this database and **Not The original Database** *(if you click show all files then go to the bin/debug file and then open with database explorer you can see the data imputed on the last debug/running)*

To fix this you need to do the following:

Your connection string

```
 con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RoomBookingSystem.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
```

Will connect to the database within the bin folder mentioned previously.

You need to go into your **app.config** file find the specific location for your database and use this for you connection string, this will allow you to insert/update data from the non copy of the database.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different Sql Commands when only one `SqlCommand` is needed. Add the parameters to `inscmd` rather than `cmd`.

So simply remove this line :

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
```

and do this for the rest :

```
inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffInitials", lblStaffInitials.Text.Trim())
.....
.....
```

Another thing to note, you don't need this :

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString)
```

Change your code like this :

```
Try
 con.Open()
 inscmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Booking (Week, Day, Period, Subject, YearGroup, StaffInitials,NumberOfPupils,Session,Room,ControlledAssesment) VALUES (@Week,@Day,@Period,@Subject,@YearGroup,@StaffInitials, @NumberOfPupils,@Session,@Room,@ControlledAssesment)"
 inscmd.Connection = con
 inscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 inscmd.Parameters.Clear()

 Catch ex As Exception
     // use message box to read the error (if there is any). or simply read the
     // ex.Message in debuggin mode.
 Finally
     con.Close()
 End Try
```

and by the way I don't see where you are setting this property `con.ConnectionString`. where is your connection string?

Comment: Have made the change as suggested but still nothing happens and no errors appearing...

Comment: Have made the changes suggested and still no result from this. No errors again.

Comment: @AlwynGardner have you set the connectionstring?

Comment: Yes I have done so and I know this works as I can read from but cannot write to.

Comment: @AlwynGardner what I'm trying to tell you is that I didn't find where you are setting the connectionstring in the code you posted. How would a new connection know the connection string by itself?

Comment: This is in the above code showing the connection string:
`con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RoomBookingSystem.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1").ConnectionString`